# how to read html file from azure storage explorer

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-explorer

how to read .html file from Azure storage explorer.
through connectionstring can able to access blob.
string Template = bloburl + "file.html";

Comment: blob. string Template = bloburl + "file.html"; via this i can able to access storage explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                        var url = TemplateMain;
                        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
```

i have tried using GetStringAsync and its working fine.

[image: GetStringAsync]

Comment: for reference. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2gZldpolvs&ab_channel=gavilanch3

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could create the html and save it to the container created.

You could make the URI for this blob public and then access it via your custom URL -- you'd have to create a CNAME for the storage container first.

Here is a good resource on how to use Blob Storage from .NET:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/